# Ports needed for IP Subnet discovery Kaspersky Security Center 10

Tags: ip, subnet, anti-virus, discovery

I'm trying to discover computers based on IP subnets. 
The administration server is not part of the same workgroup or active-directory as the clients, so this is the only way to do it.

I can discover about 1/3-1/2 of my computers.

I tried disabling the windows firewall totaly on one of the computers, and it seemed to add itself to the list of unmanaged computers.

When just opening for ICMPv4, so the management server can ping the target client-computer it does not work.

It looks like I'm missing some ports that needs to be open in the windows firewall - but the great internet can't tell me which ports!

Have anyone done this before, and got a clue about what ports I'm missing? Disabling Windows Firewall for all clients, to install the Kaspersky one is not much of a solution.....

Comment: You may find this interesting http://support.kaspersky.com/us/9297

Comment: @krisFR Thanks for the hint - but unfortunately, none of that helps.. Seems like I've found a solution - so I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the ICMP, Kaspersky Security Center uses NETBIOS to communicate with it's clients. The problem I ran in to was that Windows 8 have disabled "file and printer-sharing" in addition to ICMP in the Windows Firewall.

When allowing both those to pass, the clients show up!